# Tem como saber o tamanho do request no navegador?

Tags: navegador-de-internet, request

gostaria de saber se tem como saber o tamanho de um request pela aba **Network** do navegador. Já procurei por tudo mas não encontrei.

Comment: Request é o conteúdo que o client-side envia a um servidor, a aba "Tamanho" no Chrome se refere ao Request + Response (incluindo headers) no Firefox a aba se chama "Transferido" (Firefox) e se refere somente ao Response (resposta baixada do servidor), para conferir o tamanho do que foi enviado em POST você pode consultar o Content-Length, exemplo: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHKLV.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para fins didáticos, pode-se usar o tamanho está indicado no campo "tamanho" quando se quer medir o tamanho da request + response, ou mais específico para tamanho da request o "content-length" da seção "Cabeçalhos de Solicitação".
Se você é programador, sugiro que veja o tamanho da requisição via programação, e não via browser, pois dependendo de cada browser ainda tem variação na definição dos tamanhos...
Abaixo onde você encontra o campo "tamanho" (navegador Edge):

[image: Navegador Edge - Tamanho]

E aqui o "content-length" (navegador Edge):

[image: Navegador Edge - Content-Length]

Comment: Realmente, eu estava com a requisição aberta, ocultando essas informações. Muito obrigado!!

Comment: Isso não é o tamanho do **Request** (requisição) é o tamanho do **Response** + **Request** (payload enviado e download do conteudo baixado/transferido). cc @AdrielRosanelli **[editado]**

Comment: Quase isso. Se parar com o mouse em cima do valor, vc vê o texto "428b transferred over network" no caso do Edge. Portanto, não seria nem do Request e nem do Response especificamente... Acredito que isso aí é apenas um orientativo, pois se quem está perguntando estiver programando, esta informação não deve ser vista pelo navegador, mas sim no código.

Comment: A pergunta é sobre como saber o tamanho do request. Se vc mesmo diz que isso não é o request e nem o response, então não responde à pergunta. E se "*esta informação não deve ser vista pelo navegador, mas sim no código*", então esta orientação deveria estar na resposta. cc @AdrielRosanelli

Comment: @RicardoMerinhoFernandes editei meu primeiro comment atualizado. ps: no Firefox realmente é só o tamanho do Response, no Chrome que é "geral". De qualquer forma o tamanho do Response enviado só pode ser visto via Content-Length, quando enviado um corpo (geralmente POST e PUT). Resumindo, pra pegar o tamanho exato tem que ficar fazendo "contas", provavelmente vai ter maior facilitar se usar ferramentas como WireShark ou httpwatch (no httpwatch fora o programa creio q precisa do addon para "vincular")

Comment: Ok, @GuilhermeNascimento.